# could not import package in go

Tags: go, package

I have installed **go1.16.3 darwin/amd64**

go env

```
GOPATH="/Users/hariwarshan/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

using vscode.
In GOPATH/src/github.com/{username}/first

inside that am having main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

}
```

when i try to import mux, all I can see is the below problem

```
could not import github.com/gorilla/mux (cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of 
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
/Users/hariwarshan/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH))
```

I have two questions.

1. I gave the command **go get github.com/gorilla/mux** inside the directory where main.go is located (GOPATH/src/github.com/{username}/first). is that correct?
2. where do the installed files go. I can see a folder called mux is placed inside *GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com* .If its installed there, why as the problem states its looking inside *src/github.com* rather than *pkg/mod/github.com*?

I even tried giving **go mod init** and **go mod tidy** inside the *GOPATH/src/github.com/{username}/first* and nothing is working.

please someone help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using modules, you don't need to be in `GOPATH/src`. Take a look at the getting started tutorial and go step by step to see how that may differ from what you have done.

Comment: In 2021 you should be using modules and not `$GOPATH`. Please take a look at my answer below to read about how to set your env up using official tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I recommend going through the following path, using official documentation pages:

1. Read about [properly installing Go for your platform](https://golang.org/doc/install).
2. Read the [getting started tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) which also tells you how to install 3rd-party packages and use them in your code.

It should take you no more than 20 minutes to go through these steps, and it's almost certain that you'll be able to accomplish your goal by the end of the process. As a bonus, keep going through the Getting Started guide beyond the first page to learn how to create your own Go modules, use them from other modules, write tests, `build` your code into a binary, and more.

This is IMHO the minimal background required to even try writing Go programs; without going through these steps, you will lack crucial fundamental understanding and it will be hard to even understand SO answers.